# LightRoom presets

Tags: lightroom, presets

I'm looking into LightRoom presets right now, I was wondering if there was a hub or general resources with these sort of presets which are readily available for download?

I also wanted to know how to save a preset that I create myself so that I can share it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Matthew! It seems you have two questions, so please post them separately. Of course don't forget to do some research beforehand (and include it in your question), I suspect your second question can be answered using the LR help files.

Comment: i suggest putting the words "LightRoom presets" into the search engine of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

> I also wanted to know how to save a preset that I create myself so that I can share it?

[I'd advise you read Adobe's docs.](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/plug-ins.html)

> I was wondering if there was a hub or general resources with these sort of presets which are readily available for download?

[Let me Google that for you.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Lightroom%20presets)

Comment: +1 for putting more effort in your question than the OP put in his research. (Another mental +1 for LMGTFY.) ;-)

Comment: @flolilolilo - I was feelin' a bit snarky this morning :-D